# Flutter: How to get audio response from pages when its loaded for the first time?

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech

I want to be able to navigate to pages and when I go to a page it should read out (audio) the title of the page. ( not onpressed button, just when it's loaded.)

Comment: are you asking about the audio implementation or triggering the audio on the first load? or both?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start some function or anything when page on loading, just put that code under `initState()` block function.